# java- how to run JAR file in Windows command line which has run time arguments containing "<" and ">" chars

Tags: java, windows, jar, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a JAR file that accepts 3 arguments.
This is my command-

```
c:\Arvind_gpd>java -jar icasae.jar c:\Arvind_gpd\inv_new <data> </data>
```

However I am getting this error0

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

How do I pass the parameters `"<data>"` and `"</data>"` correctly in my invocation of the JAR file so that the execution is successful.

Comment: I think caret (^) should escape those

Comment: Maybe enclose the arguments in double quotes?

Comment: @ignis is right, put them in double quotes, caret does not work

Comment: Thanks @MiserableVariable for confirming, I'm turning this into an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the arguments in double quotes.

Comment: This solution also works when you want to pass a JSON string as argument